# Python pd.read_csv() pass arguments dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

Just wondering if there is a way to pass the other arguments than path for the pd.read_csv dynamically ?

```
filepath='c:\works\abcd.csv'
args = {"delimiter":"|","index_col":"None"}
df=pd.read_csv(filepath,args)
```

my requirement is to pass multiple parameters like that dynamically.

Comment: Are you familiar with *args and **kwargs?

Comment: pd.read_csv(**filepath,args)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What does ** mean in pyhton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-double-star-operator-mean-in-python/)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

filepath="""1|2|3|4
A|B|C|D"""
args = {"delimiter": "|", "index_col": None}
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(filepath), **args)
```